# I can't save my files as a .png in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, cs6, save

Im creating an app icon for my iOS app, but there is no option for me to save my file as a `.png` file. The only format for app icons is a `.png` file. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Is your document in CMYK or RGB?

Comment: @JohnB it is in RGB

Comment: Try to reset photoshop preferences. On mac press hotkeys: `Cmd+Alt+Shift` and click to open photoshop. Keep pressing the keys until it asks for confirmations on wether or not you wanna reset. --- On windows: `Ctrl+Alt+Shift`. I believe on windows you have to start opening it and then immediately press those hotkeys, cause otherwise it should open windows application properties or something.

Comment: is it a 16 bit file?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ensure your document is 8-bit RGB. (`Image > Mode`)

If that doesn't help, hold down the <kbd>Option/alt</kbd> key and choose `File > Save as...` this will save a copy and remove any non-png allowed formatting.

Chances are there's simply something about the image which is not allowed in the PNG format. However, using `File > Save for Web` should allow PNG saving in almost all cases.

You really haven't provided **any** details beyond *"My Adobe don't work."*

Answer (score 2):

The 2 main answers to this problem are:

1) Recreate your file as an RGB and copy all your old layers over to this new file.

2) As Adobe STAFF has said, you may have deleted some important files by mistake requiring a reinstall of Photoshop

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1311499

Comment: Link only answers tend to be frowned upon on the basis that if that link were to go down your link would serve no value.  Do you mind giving some detail on what the link is about.

Comment: @Matt Yes I agree 100%, which is why I gave a run down of the link: "you may have deleted some important files by mistake requiring a reinstall of Photoshop". I was hoping this was sufficient, feel free to correct me if it is not explained enough.